# Check if relation exist with foreign entity in Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have an instance `$person` of `Person` and want to check if there is a relation created to a foreign entity (`App`).

```
people: id
people_apps: person_id, app_id
apps: id
```

The relationships are properly mapped in the Eloquent models. **What is the preferred way to check this?**

The only way I can think of is something like

```
$foundApp = $person->apps->filter(function($a) use($searchAppId)
{ 
  return $a->id == $searchAppId; 
});

if ($foundApp) {}
```

but there's probably a better way.

Comment: I would simply check to see if the size of the array holding the person's apps is larger than 0.

Comment: @Dave I need to check for a specific app id

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom getter that checks  in your model

```php
class Person extends Eloquent {

  public function getHasAppWithId($id){
    return ($this->apps()->where('id', $id)->count() > 0);
  }

}
```

In your code

```php
$person->hasAppWithId(25);
```

Comment: Why not just call the method `hasAppWithId`?

Comment: Mm, you can remove the get. When I started typing this, i was creating a custom getter, but thats not possible when you need to give an id.